# Unable to copy file / Unable to copy obj C# error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

My code sample:

```cs
internal class NewBaseType
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter first word");
        string v = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("enter second word");
        string w = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Result: "
            + v
            + " "
            + w);
    }
}
```

This code works great in a online c# playgrounds.

But Visual studio code gives me errors:
[image]

> Unable to copy obj

> Unable to copy file

```json
[{
    "resource": "/c:/Program Files/dotnet/sdk/6.0.300/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets",
    "owner": "msCompile",
    "code": "MSB3027",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Could not copy \"obj",
    "startLineNumber": 4632,
    "startColumn": 5,
    "endLineNumber": 4632,
    "endColumn": 5
}]
```

And when I run the code I get this:
[image]

> Errors exists after running preLaunchTask 'build'
>
> Debug Anyway / Show errors / Abort

Where I was wrong and how to fix that?

Comment: Is your app running in any window?

Comment: maybe try running your IDE as admin or manually delete your bin and obj directories in your project directory. Also check if your antivirus software did something